# How to embed external script to my page without breaking other script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dependencies

Hi I work on this issue more than 2 weeks now and I can't find the right way to embed my script code to my page without creating an error in my console from another js file uploaded by my theme.

This embed code gives me the possibility to add a calendar and book now button from the lodgify service, as you can see it in my page, the right black sidebar with book now info. And to be honest I don't know why it generate an error.

I mean that all works fine in my website before to embed my script, and when I embed it, an error occurred. I've tried a lot of different ways but without success, I always have the same error from the same file. At the end I tried to load my embed code after the file in question but nothing changed for me.

Here is my [link](http://www.rental.booclin.ovh/la-calado/) if you want to check the console and may be explain me something that I did not see yet.

**Here is my embed code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.lodgify.com/themes/shared/v3/assets/latest/embed-ldgfy-book.min.js" async="async" style="display:block!important" class="embed-ldgfy-script-loader embed-ldgfy-book-script-loader" id="lodgify-script-book-now-box" data-website-id="27****79" data-website-slug="antibesrental" data-domain="lodgify.com" data-protocol="https" data-property-id="27****26" data-culture="en" data-culture-iso="en-US" data-currency="EUR" data-token="oHwmNCP**********o5s"></script>
```

**Here is how I add it to my page:**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#content").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.lodgify.com/themes/shared/v3/assets/latest/embed-ldgfy-book.min.js" async="async" style="display:block!important" class="embed-ldgfy-script-loader embed-ldgfy-book-script-loader" id="lodgify-script-book-now-box" data-website-id="27****79" data-website-slug="antibesrental" data-domain="lodgify.com" data-protocol="https" data-property-id="27****26" data-culture="en" data-culture-iso="en-US" data-currency="EUR" data-token="oHwmNCP**********o5s"></'+'script>');
});
</script>
```

**Here is the error when I add it to my page:**

> TypeError: $elm.airtifactFitVids is not a function. (In
>   '$elm.airtifactFitVids()', '$elm.airtifactFitVids' is undefined).

**Here is the part of code from the main-build.js who is concerned:**

```
// VARIOUS FUNCTIONS INIT
    _initFitVid: function( $elm ) {
        $elm.airtifactFitVids();
    },

    _initTwitterFeed: function( $elm ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your script loaded/embeded correctly inside the page.
See your network calls in DevTools. May be anything wrong with any method call or error in defining a function.

See the following image:

[image: Chrome DevTools]

Comment: yep it's loaded perfectly but an error is generated when this embed script is present in my page and the error disappear when I delete the src from my embed script ? please check the console, you will see this error from my main-build.js (theme's js file): TypeError: $elm.airtifactFitVids is not a function. (In '$elm.airtifactFitVids()', '$elm.airtifactFitVids' is undefined).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the support solution if it can help:**

Our team has had a look to see whether there is anything on our side that was going wrong. However, I'm happy to say that the widget runs as it should.

Instead, the issue is that our widget and your theme seem to be using the same library. Basically, the solution to use both the theme and our widget with full functionality on both, **would be to have them each load in a separate library, so that the codes can't conflict**.

Just to be clear, we are echoing what the theme owner let you know as well: The theme is not at fault here, and neither are we. **As the two were not developed to work with each other specifically, unfortunately this is something that can occur**. But like they said, **making the customization of separating the libraries.**

This is the reason why it doesn't work: as you can see the issue comes from a conflict that could not be planned or foreseen and, as much as we would like to help this cannot be solved by us.